# Directive in view not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using `yo angular` to create a quick testing environment for learning Angular. Everything works as it should but then I'm starting to experiment:

The app is defined in `app.js` and looks like this

```
angular
  .module('angularApp', [
    // ...
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      // ...
  });
```

and the `main.js` contains the following:

```
angular.module('angularApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      // ...
    ];
  });
```

Now I thought "hey, I want to have my own directive inside of the main template `views/main.html`".

So I created `contact.js`, linked it in the `index.html` and wrote the following lines:

```
angular.module('angularApp')
  .directive('myDir', function () {
    'use strict';
    return {
      template: 'Testing'
    };
  });
```

Now I added `<my-dir></my-dir>` to `views/main.html` but when inspecting the elements, `<my-dir></my-dir>` is still there and not replaced.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `replace: true` to the template definition object

Comment: Check your console for errors. It should work: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SX4M2/)

Comment: When you create a directive, it is restricted to attribute only by default.  Specify restrict:'E' in your directive definition for an Element directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in app.js    use,

```
 var app= angular.module('angularApp', []).config ...
```

Now use this var app in contact.js like this,

```
app.directive('myDir',function(){

   restrict:"E",
   replace:true,
   template:'<div> Testing </div>'

});
```

and then register your contact.js in index page...

now in every .js file use this 'app' var (as shown in contact.js) rather than using angular.modue(...).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'm only using the global angular because of the yo generator. But thanks for the advice!

Comment: can you tell me what is that, yo angular? I'd like to know.

Comment: http://yeoman.io - just a website generator where you have sort of "templates" to start through.